# replace/prepare raw POST data before using HttpServletRequest in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have api-based client-server application, php+yii as backend. My goal is to make port of backend part from php to java (compatible with old queries from client).

I chose Spring MVC framework, but got stuck on problem with decrypting raw post data. The issue is that old client uses custom encryption algorithm, so `HttpServletRequest.getParameterMap()` doesn't return valid map.

So, my question is: In this situation, what is the best solution for replacing/preparing raw post data (decrypting) before using `request.getParameterMap()` method for pure business logic?

Controller code is something like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public class ApiController {

    @RequestMapping
    @ResponseBody
    public String process(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ApiQueryResponse queryResponse = new ApiQueryResponse();

        try {
            // request = APIEncryptor.decrypt(request);         // 1
            // now working with request.getParameterMap()       // 2
            // ...
            queryResponse.setText(APIEncryptor.crypt(...))
        } catch (Exception e) {
            queryResponse.setError(e.getMessage());
        }

        return queryResponse.asText();
    }

    ...

}
```

APIEncryptor code is something like this:

```
public class ApiEncryptor {
    public static ApiQueryData encrypt(Java Object) {
        // custom encryption algorithm...
        return Raw data string;
    }

    // input post data: 103klg20fsl2g2fsldkfj20f9isjf
    // output post data: a=1&b=2&c=3&d=some_text

    public static ApiQueryData decrypt(Raw post data...) {
        // decrypt algorithm...
        return request; // HttpServletRequest object with valid post data
        // after this action, .getParameter() will produce valid data
    }
}
```

note: I know what method such as `request.getInputStream()` exists, but I don't need it right now. I need to know is there any way to just prepare post data before using HttpServletRequest parameter getters? OR (anyway) I need to get post data from request once and do what I want (by getReader(), for example)?

Answer (score 2):

> The best way to handle your decryption logic is inside a http filter
>   (uses spring MVC) as below. This filter decrypts the requests
>   immediately after receiving the request to server and before reaching
>   the controller method.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

public class DecryptionFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        request = ApiEncryptor.decrypt(request);

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for advice! additional question arises here - can I override request parameters or change source of which it forms parameters map, when I call getParameterMap() in controller's process method?

Comment: I think that HttpRequestWrapper class might help you.

Answer (score 1):

> HttpServletRequest Decrypt before controller in Filter with Spring Boot and java 8

```
public class RequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

private final String body;

public RequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    super(request);

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
            int bytesRead = -1;
            while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
                stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        } else {
            stringBuilder.append("");
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        if (bufferedReader != null) {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
    String encryptData = stringBuilder.toString();
    String deCryptData = null;
    if (encryptData != null && !encryptData.isEmpty()) {
        deCryptData = MD5Utils.decrypt(encryptData);
        if (deCryptData == null) {
            //logger.error("Exception occured inside MD5Utils.decrypt(encryptData) - Request Body not valid : ");
        }
    }
    body = deCryptData;
}

@Override
public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes());
    ServletInputStream servletInputStream = new ServletInputStream() {
        public int read() throws IOException {
            return byteArrayInputStream.read();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isFinished() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isReady() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void setReadListener(ReadListener listener) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
    return servletInputStream;
}

@Override
public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
    return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getInputStream()));
}

public String getBody() {
    return this.body;
}
```

}

Filter class

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter {
  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    /* wrap the request in order to read the inputstream multiple times */
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    request = new RequestWrapper(httpServletRequest);  

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
}
```